# Log data into grafana for every minute

Tags: jmx, grafana, graphite, spring-boot-actuator, codahale-metrics

The below code registers five metrics count, oneminuteRate, fiftenMinuteRate, fiveMinuteRate, meanRate into graphite for every 30 seconds from my application.

```
public void collectMetric(string metricName, long metricValue){
        mr.meter(metricName).mark(value)
    }
```

I would like to show in the Grafana dashboard the no of requests that are received every minute.(i,e if in the first minute 60 is received, in the second minute 120 is received) Since the count in the meter metric above just keeps increasing and all the *Rate values are events per second. I am not sure how to log metric into Grafana dashboard that displays the no of requests received per minute. Any advice is highly appreciated?

Suppose if I use
`mr.counter(metricName).inc(value)` IS there a way to reset the counters every 1 minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. The way that I found is that I resolved this in Grafana.
When you're on the panel's metrics, you can add a function to your query like this:

[image: Screenshot]

You can try the `derivative()` function or `perSecond()` function but these functions are not completly reliable, it depends what you're doing with these in your panel.
But with these you'll see the number of input in time and not the total.

Comment: I have two metrics success and count which is taken using the per-second function. How do we calculate the percentage of success in another panel?

Comment: u can add a function like `asPercent(<your metric>,<the maximum>)`.

Comment: What is the order to use persecond and hitcount(1minute) when aggregating the metric count based on a minute

Comment: Do you mean the which function you have to put inside the other ? Sorry i don't understand your point.